# How to setup a shell account provider?

Tags: linux, ssh, ddos

I want to provide ssh/shell access to one server, is similar to what you can find here https://shells.red-pill.eu/. what should i keep in mind before giving access?

I was thinking on 
* cgrups (memory limit)
* disk quotas

what else should i think of before giving access? i want to avoid abuse of the server/network before hand.

Thank you!

Comment: Based on the things you are asking about, it sounds like this is more of a server admin question than a security question.  How many resources to give someone on a server is not security related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will surely have to handle a whole truckload of messy things if you really want to do that. And if you are doing this alone, it's way more than you can probably handle.

Assume that **every user** will try his best to abuse your server, attack other servers, mine cryptocurrencies, send spam, host porn and warez, steal each other passwords. And you will have a small army of misbehaving users doing that all the time.

First, you will have to harden the server **as paranoid as you can**, it will have to be barely usable to be harder to be abusable. List all SUID programs you have, and determine if they all need SUID. Remove the SUID bit from any program you can live without.

Subscribe to all security lists you friend Google can give you. And follow them. You must be sure to patch any bug on the programs you have as soon as you know there's a bug, because your users will know before you and will exploit. Have a policy that allows you to reboot the server any time you want, with no forward notice, for any reason. Patch and reboot.

Properly configure SELinux or AppArmor on the server. They will help you keep your clients away from each other, and will log misbehaving programs or users. Use the logs to ban users later.

You will have to setup a beefy firewall, with both **ingress and egress filtering** to limit the traffic to known bad places. Dropping all Tor traffic will be good. And define traffic shaping, and bandwidth allocation and allowances by user. And ban UDP. And torrent, and DHT, and anything  loosely related to P2P.

Put a good IPS/IDS in place on the server, and on the gateway. If anyone gets root on your server, he can put a rootkit on the server and mask his activities. Having a IPS/IDS on another server will help you detect discrepancies. And secure that gateway the better you can. It will probably be the prime target for hacking.

You would like to remove compilers and a lot of interpreters from the server, so your users will have less room to misbehave. And limit the disk quota. And mount /tmp with the `noexec` flag. And mount /home with `noexec` too. And hunt down every world writable file/directory, and change the permissions. World writable directories are easy to abuse.

And **log everything**. Twice. On the local server, and on a remote server, a hardened and hard to access server. When someone from your server abuses another party, you may be liable to some extent. Having documented all access will help you steer the blame away to the user.

And use a log manager (like Splunk). You will not be able to read all the logs you will be generating and parsing them by hand. A log manager will help you detect faster when someone abused the server, and kick them as soon as possible.

Have a draconian TOS, EULA, Service Agreement. The most draconian your draconian lawyer is able to write. And **have one lawyer write it**, so it will be valid when you have to sue one user who used your server to commit fraud. And be the BSfH (Bastard Sysadmin from Hell) when dealing with them. Don't let your users break any rule twice, kick them out of the door on the first offence.

And don't even think about providing this for free. You must have some way to punish the bad users, and having them paying first and using later, and losing access if they abuse your service can turn down some bad users. Charging someone 500 USD for *Abuse fee* (with all supporting documentation) will help you.

And securing you server is not an activity, it's a day to day routine. Every day you will have to harden something.

And I wish you luck.